# Rails 3.2 + table tag + background property + url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In /config/environment/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://192.155.90.155:3000"
```

In my mail body I would like to see:

```
<table background="http://192.155.90.155:3000/assets/fb.png">
```

`<table background="<%= url_for('assets/bg.jpg', :only_path => false) %>">` gives me en error.

And `<table background="<%= url_for('assets/bg.jpg') %>">` gives me unexpected result:

```
<table background="assets/fb.png">
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

use `<table background="<%= asset_path 'bg.jpg' %>">`

instead of `<table background="<%= url_for('assets/bg.jpg') %>">`